# What is "GENESIS_FORK_VERSION", "GENESIS_VALIDATORS_ROOT"?

Tags: go-ethereum, eth-2.0, staking

When we make a deposit_data, we use **staking-deposit-cli**.
There's option called "--chain" that we can choose a network like mainnet, goerli, prater, sepolia, zhejiang, holesky~ not the private chain.

So I want to make my own deposit_data to use for my private network.

I need to change some code from https://github.com/ethereum/staking-deposit-cli/blob/master/staking_deposit/settings.py, to use it for my network, but i don't get it what is "GENESIS_FORK_VERSION", "GENESIS_VALIDATORS_ROOT" in that settings.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it, we can get it from beacon api /eth/v1/beacon/genesis